# Extracting metadata(latitude,longitude,date created,manufacturer) from Bytestream

Tags: arrays, image, metadata, latitude-longitude, exif

I am trying to convert a image having metadata(latitude,longitude,date created,manufacturer) into a Bytestream. which I am able to do.
But while constructing back Image from Bytestream, the metadata(latitude,longitude,date created,manufacturer) is not present in the new image whicch is constructed by the bytestream.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9INZ.png)

```
enter code here
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;   
import org.apache.sanselan.ImageReadException;
import org.apache.sanselan.Sanselan;
import org.apache.sanselan.common.IImageMetadata;
import org.apache.sanselan.common.RationalNumber;
import org.apache.sanselan.formats.jpeg.JpegImageMetadata;
import org.apache.sanselan.formats.tiff.TiffField;
import org.apache.sanselan.formats.tiff.TiffImageMetadata;
import org.apache.sanselan.formats.tiff.constants.ExifTagConstants;
import org.apache.sanselan.formats.tiff.constants.GPSTagConstants;
import org.apache.sanselan.formats.tiff.constants.TagInfo;
import org.apache.sanselan.formats.tiff.constants.TiffTagConstants;

 public class SimpleConvertImage {
public static String decoder(String bytestream){
    System.out.println("Image Successfully created from Bytestream");
    String dirName="C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\";
    try
    {

          byte[] bytearray = Base64.getDecoder().decode(bytestream);

        BufferedImage imag=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytearray));
        ImageIO.write(imag, "jpg", new File(dirName,"img.jpg"));
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
    String path=dirName+"img.jpg";
    return path;
}

  public static void metadataExample(final File file) throws ImageReadException,IOException {

       final IImageMetadata metadata =  Sanselan.getMetadata(file);

    if (metadata instanceof JpegImageMetadata) {
        final JpegImageMetadata jpegMetadata = (JpegImageMetadata) metadata;
        System.out.println("file: " + file.getPath());
        System.out.println();
        String manufacturer = jpegMetadata.findEXIFValueWithExactMatch(TiffTagConstants.TIFF_TAG_MAKE).getStringValue();
        String model = jpegMetadata.findEXIFValueWithExactMatch(TiffTagConstants.TIFF_TAG_MODEL).getStringValue();
        System.out.println("Manufacturer: "+ manufacturer+", Model: " + model);
        System.out.println();

        printTagValue(jpegMetadata,ExifTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_DATE_TIME_ORIGINAL);
        printTagValue(jpegMetadata,GPSTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
        printTagValue(jpegMetadata, GPSTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
        printTagValue(jpegMetadata,GPSTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);
        printTagValue(jpegMetadata, GPSTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);

        System.out.println();

        final TiffImageMetadata exifMetadata = jpegMetadata.getExif();
        if(exifMetadata !=null) {
            final TiffImageMetadata.GPSInfo gpsInfo = exifMetadata.getGPS();
            if (gpsInfo!=null) {
                final String gpsDescription = gpsInfo.toString();
                final double longitude = gpsInfo.getLongitudeAsDegreesEast();
                final double latitude = gpsInfo.getLatitudeAsDegreesNorth();
                System.out.println("GPS Description: "+ gpsDescription);
                System.out.println("GPS Longitude (Degrees East): " + longitude);
                System.out.println("GPS Latitude (Degrees North): " + latitude);
            }
        }

        final TiffField gpsLatitudeRefField = jpegMetadata.findEXIFValueWithExactMatch(GPSTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
        final TiffField gpsLatitudeField = jpegMetadata.findEXIFValueWithExactMatch(GPSTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
        final TiffField gpsLongitudeRefField = jpegMetadata.findEXIFValueWithExactMatch(GPSTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);
        final TiffField gpsLongitudeField = jpegMetadata.findEXIFValueWithExactMatch(GPSTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
        if (gpsLatitudeRefField != null && gpsLatitudeField != null && gpsLongitudeRefField != null && gpsLongitudeField != null) 
        {
            final String gpsLatitudeRef = (String) gpsLatitudeRefField.getValue();
            final RationalNumber gpsLatitude[] = (RationalNumber[]) (gpsLatitudeField.getValue());
            final String gpsLongitudeRef = (String) gpsLongitudeRefField.getValue();
            final RationalNumber gpsLongitude[] = (RationalNumber[]) gpsLongitudeField.getValue();

            final RationalNumber gpsLatitudeDegrees = gpsLatitude[0];
            final RationalNumber gpsLatitudeMinutes = gpsLatitude[1];
            final RationalNumber gpsLatitudeSeconds = gpsLatitude[2];

            final RationalNumber gpsLongitudeDegrees = gpsLongitude[0];
            final RationalNumber gpsLongitudeMinutes = gpsLongitude[1];
            final RationalNumber gpsLongitudeSeconds = gpsLongitude[2];

            System.out.println("    " + "GPS Latitude: "
                    + gpsLatitudeDegrees.toDisplayString() + " degrees, "
                    + gpsLatitudeMinutes.toDisplayString() + " minutes, "
                    + gpsLatitudeSeconds.toDisplayString() + " seconds "
                    + gpsLatitudeRef);
            System.out.println("    " + "GPS Longitude: "
                    + gpsLongitudeDegrees.toDisplayString() + " degrees, "
                    + gpsLongitudeMinutes.toDisplayString() + " minutes, "
                    + gpsLongitudeSeconds.toDisplayString() + " seconds "
                    + gpsLongitudeRef);

        }

        System.out.println();
    }
  }
  private static void printTagValue(final JpegImageMetadata jpegMetadata,final TagInfo tagInfo) {
      final TiffField field = jpegMetadata.findEXIFValueWithExactMatch(tagInfo);
      if (field == null)
          System.out.println(tagInfo.name + ": " + "Not Found.");
      else 
          System.out.println(tagInfo.name + ": "+ field.getValueDescription());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    try{
        String bytestream="Enter STRING BYTESTREAM HERE";
        String path=decoder(bytestream);
        metadataExample(new File(path.replace("\\", "\\\\")));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION");
    }

}}
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use [ExifTool by Phil Harvey](https://exiftool.org/) for that! The page also offers some Java wrappers, see under [Programming](https://exiftool.org/#related_prog)

Comment: i want to read image metadata from bytestream only. Is it possible or not

Comment: Should be possible also with exiftool, see https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=3394.0